# How to avoid echoing large swathes of javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

This is CodeIgniter on PHP.

In my (MVC) view, I've got a loop that creates a small flot graph (javascript) for each instance of the loop.

```
<?php
for each ($catalog as $book) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo anchor('controller/manager/'.$key['Title']) . ' is available';

      // flot javascript goes here to generate a small graph for this list item

}
unset ($book);      ?>
```

The loop itself is PHP, the javascript is probably about 50 lines or so of code, which I've developed elsewhere from some samples.

So in order to get that code to work in this View, I need to echo out each line, otherwise I break the *for each* loop when I terminate the PHP right before the javascript starts and re-decalre the php after the javascript finishes.

What is a more efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use unobtrusive JavaScript instead of coupling inline JavaScript to your backend code.

Comment: The ideal thing to do is to put the majority of your JS code into separate external files which and link to them in your view files using script tags. The script tags can either go in the HTML head or just before the closing body tag. I prefer the later as it's generally faster in terms of page load times. jQuery makes it easier to write JS this way B/C it provides simple cross-browser methods for binding events to DOM elements. It also has a .ready() method that you can wrap your code in to ensure that the DOM is ready when you execute the code. The module pattern is good to incorporate, too.

Answer (score 1):

Big blocks of text/code are much easier to echo out using heredocs. PHP will still parse the block if you need to use PHP variables in your JavaScript.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

```
$some_javascript = <<<_JS
some mulit-
line text
<<<_JS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use short tags to feed data from your controller to the javascript sections of your view.

For example we use the following javascript code in the view:

```
    var assign_data = [
    {label : "Single", data:<?= $single_num ?>},
    {label : "Barcode", data:<?= $barcode_num ?>},
    {label : "Template", data:<?= $template_num ?>}

];
```

For this graph, we then grab the corresponding number from a model, and then assign it the corresponding short tag to get rendered by flot. So, for $barcode_num, we use the following code:

```
    $data['barcode_num'] = $this->history_model->get_barcode_assign_num($this->org_id);
```

We also build a formatted string in a controller to provide flot data as well. An example output from one controller method provides this sample string for a bar graph.  :

```
          data: [ [144,4],[157,0],[138,0],[145,0],[149,0],[141,0],[137,3],[155,0],[150,0],[142,0],[148,0],[140,0],[146,0],[152,0],[153,0],[147,1],[143,0],[156,0],[139,1],[154,0],[151,0] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use hmtl5 data attributes to pass your metrics for the graph's.
You could use a library to bind data to these elements also, libraries such as knockout.js, or
angular.js then work on the javascript client side, exactly like Neil say's.

**The View:**

```
<ul id="book-graph">
   <?php foreach($books as $book): ?>
        <li id="book_id_<?php echo $book->id;?>">
           <span id="graph" data-bind="metric : <?php echo $book->metric;?>">&nbsp;</span>
        </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**//Jquery Example**

```
(function($){

   var GraphAPI = {
        init : function(){
            if($("#book-graph"))
                this.drawBookGraph();
        },
        drawBookGraph : function(){
            //Your graph code
        }
   };

   $(function(){
        //Load up your graph API when your ready
        GraphAPI.init();
   });

}(jQuery));
```